# How to resolve children params in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I've been working on a POC with Angular 2 and I've found a issue: I can't get the child component route param.

As you can see (the code is bellow), I have a parent component name ItemDetailComponent which shows detail information about an item based on the item/{id} path param (required param).

Inside this component I have a child named RecommendationComponent which its responsible for showing up all the recommendations about a given item (again, based on the {id} path param).

The problem its that I can't resolve (ItemRecommendationResolver illustred bellow) the item/{id}recommendations deps because the ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params dosn't have the {id} registered.

Given the following components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'item-detail',
  providers: [],
  directives: [ProductDetailCardcomponent, RecommendationComponent],
  styles: [],
  templateUrl: './item-detailtemplate.html'
})
```

and the recommendation.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'recommendations',
  styles: [],
  providers: [],
  templateUrl: './recommendation.template.html',
  directives: []
})

export class ItemDetailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private item: any;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getItems();
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub)
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

  public getItems() {
    let id= this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.itemService
        .getItem(id)
        .subscribe(item => this.item = item);
    });
  }
}
```

and the item.routes.ts

```
export const itemRoutes Routes: RouterConfig = [
      {
        path: 'items',
        component: ItemComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'items/:id',
        component: ItemDetailComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'recommendations',
            component: RecommendationComponent,
            resolve: {
              recommendations: ItemRecommendationResolver
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

and the recommendation.component

```
export class RecommendationComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private recommendations: any;
  private errorMessage: any;
  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

  getRecommendations() {
    this.sub = this.router.routerState.parent(this.route).params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = params["id"];
    });
    this.route
      .data
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.recommendations = data.recommendations;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRecommendations();
  }
}
```

and the item.resolver

```
@Injectable()
export class ItemRecommendationResolver implements Resolve<any>, OnDestroy {
  constructor(private itemService: ItemService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }
  private sub: any;

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
     let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id']; // can't get the item/{id} value. So I won't be able to retrieve the item recommendations.
     return this.itemService.getItemsRecommendations(id);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub)
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}

export const ITEM_RESOLVER = [
  ItemService,
  ItemRecommendationResolver
];
```

Is there anyone that can help me, plese?

Answer (score 0):

The `route` you get in ItemRecommendationResolver is of path `recommendations`, that doesn't have id param.

If you want to get `id` you should get parent of this route and check for params. Like

```
this.router.routerState.parent(this.route).params.subscribe(params => {
  let id = params["id"];
});
```

See this [article](https://www.codementor.io/angularjs/tutorial/angular-2-route-resolves--typescript) as well

Comment: Also tried this approach, but apparently the routerState.parent() its undefined.
Got this error message: 
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of null

Do you have any other idea about how can I solve that problem?

Comment: Can you manually validate if routeState (tree of ActivatedRoute) has the info you need. Parent may return null due to reference mismatch/ non existence. If ref mismatch we can write some code to get parent from tree.

Comment: Just confirmed it. Parent its null.
How can I solve it?

Comment: this.router.routerState is a Tree<ActivatedRoute>. You can you tree iteration to get the desired ActivatedRoute